# Filter SharePoint list to only display items that were created within the past 24h

Tags: sharepoint

How to build a list view that will only show items in a list that were created or modified within the past 24/48/... hours.

Comment: Do you know there is a [dedicated Stack Exchange site for sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit View** and in the **Filter** section select column, which you want to use for filtering (**Created** or **Modified** or **both**). Then select condition **is greater than**. And insert formula **[Today]-2**. The number 2 means number of days you want to use for filtering (number 1 means 24 hours in the past, number 2 means 24 hours in the past,...).

[Image of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DdIi.png)

Please mark this as answer if it helps you.